# How to join datasets on a column with NULLs?

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have two tables, which look like this:

```
Table_1:

Shop_ID | Offer_ID | Metric_1
--------|----------|---------
AAA     | 111      | 1
AAA     | 222      | 2
BBB     | 111      | 3
BBB     | 222      | 4

Table 2:

Shop_ID | Offer_ID | Metric_2
--------|----------|---------
AAA     | 111      | 1
AAA     | 222      | 2
BBB     | 111      | 3
BBB     | 222      | 4
CCC     | 111      | 5
CCC     | 222      | 6
```

I want to join them into one combined dataset, like this:

```
Shop_ID | Offer_ID | Metric_1 | Metric_2
--------|----------|----------|---------
AAA     | 111      | 1        | 1
AAA     | 222      | 2        | 2
BBB     | 111      | 3        | 3
BBB     | 222      | 4        | 4
CCC     | 111      | NULL     | 5
CCC     | 222      | NULL     | 6
```

Does anyone know how to do this, please? I tried the following code, but it just gave me an error message saying *"Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column is not allowed"*.

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE_3
  (
    SELECT  TABLE_2.SHOP_ID,
        TABLE_2.OFFER_ID,
        METRIC_1,
        METRIC_2
    FROM    TABLE_1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        TABLE_2 
    ON  TABLE_1.SHOP_ID = TABLE_2.SHOP_ID
    AND TABLE_1.OFFER_ID = TABLE_2.OFFER_ID
    );
```

Comment: A `select` could not be generating this error.  You must be inserting into a table that has a `NOT NULL` column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks for the reply! I've edited the example code to clarify that yes, I'm trying to get the result into a table. The example is simplified to make it easier to read, but at no point does my original query have 'is not null' or '<> null' in it. It does run as a select query without error messages, but it doesn't produce the result I need; the Shop_ID 'CCC' rows are missing from the result. Do you know how best to get the results I'm looking for please?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the column Metric_1 has a [NOT NULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp) condition. You can do two things about this.

1. Alter the TABLE_3 Metric_1 column to allow NULL values

   ```
   ALTER TABLE TABLE_3
        ALTER COLUMN Metric_1 *your_data_type* NULL
   ```
2. Use the [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression. This is where you basically replace NULL values with something else. In the example below I used -1, but you can use whatever makes the most sense for you.

```sql
    INSERT INTO TABLE_3   (
          SELECT  TABLE_2.SHOP_ID,
              TABLE_2.OFFER_ID,
              ISNULL(METRIC_1,-1),
              METRIC_2
          FROM    TABLE_1
          FULL OUTER JOIN
              TABLE_2 
          ON  TABLE_1.SHOP_ID = TABLE_2.SHOP_ID
          AND TABLE_1.OFFER_ID = TABLE_2.OFFER_ID
          );
```